# What's the difference between IClonable and partial classes

Tags: c#

What's the difference between using `System.IClonable` and `partial` classes? And if there is one difference, when should one be used over the other? Are there some best practices?

Comment: How are they even similar?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. `IClonable` and partial classes have nothing to do with each other. `IClonable` declares a method `Clone` that should be implemented so that it makes a cloned instance of an existing one. `partial` classes are a compile-time feature to split the code of a class into separate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Partial Classes**

There are several situations when splitting a class definition is desirable:
When working on large projects, spreading a class over separate files enables multiple programmers to work on it at the same time.

When working with automatically generated source, code can be added to the class without having to recreate the source file. Visual Studio uses this approach when it creates Windows Forms, Web service wrapper code, and so on. You can create code that uses these classes without having to modify the file created by Visual Studio.

To split a class definition, use the partial keyword modifier, as shown here:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```

**ICloneable**

The ICloneable interface enables you to provide a customized implementation that creates a copy of an existing object. The ICloneable interface contains one member, the Clone method, which is intended to provide cloning support beyond that supplied by Object.MemberwiseClone. For more information about cloning, deep versus shallow copies, and examples, see the Object.MemberwiseClone method.

```
public interface ICloneable
```

Sources: 
[MSDN ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx)
[MSDN Partial Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The two are quite different things and don't really have anything in common.

1. [`IClonable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to clone object. To create a customized implementation of how copy an object . By MSDN:

   > Supports cloning, which creates a new instance of a class with the
   >   same value as an existing instance.
2. [Partial classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) - it is just way of splitting a file that gets to large into 2 or more different files. A common example is in winforms where one section deals with the UI and the other with the code behind